# How to Publish | Deploy | Upload an asp.net web application project to a hosting server in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, web-hosting

So basically right now I am using FileZilla Client (FTP client) and upload the whole visual sdutio project folder to my Godaddy hosting server. Yes, it works but kind of inconvenient and slow, sometime I messed everything up because I uploaded wrong files/folders accidentally.

Is there any better way/how to do that in Visual Studio 2013, I found couple of articles from MSDN of Microsoft but it is too generic and out-dated, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where/which section/forum should this question go to?

Comment: @RonaldinhoState I think your question is fine if you update it to make it clear that you're confused about how to use VS, rather than asking for us to recommend an entirely different program (which is off topic).

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as Visual Studio 2013, why not right click your project from within the project and click publish or copy web site? When you publish, you can continue to use FTP, or depending on your web server you can use Web Deploy.

For more about publishing from VS, see [How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx).